# Difference between UseHttpsRedirection and AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In the `Startup.cs` file, consider the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Irrelevant code removed

    services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
    {
        options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently;
    });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime.
// Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // Irrelevant code removed

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
        .AddRedirectToWwwPermanent()
        .AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent()
    );
}
```

As far as I know, I have to use the Rewriter to set the `AddRedirectToWwwPermanent`. My question is, should I be using both `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` and `AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent()`? Or if they doing the exact same thing, which should I remove?

I just want to make sure I'm redirecting to Https properly, in conjunction with the Www redirect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.rewrite.rewriteoptionsextensions.addredirecttohttpspermanent?view=aspnetcore-2.1) (or its sibling [`AddRedirectToHttps`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.rewrite.rewriteoptionsextensions.addredirecttohttps?view=aspnetcore-2.1)) adds a [`RedirectToHttpsRule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.rewrite.internal.redirecttohttpsrule?view=aspnetcore-2.0) to the rewriter. This rule [works like this](https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/blob/2.1.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite/Internal/RedirectToHttpsRule.cs):

```
if (!context.HttpContext.Request.IsHttps)
{
    var host = context.HttpContext.Request.Host;
    if (SSLPort.HasValue && SSLPort.Value > 0)
    {
        // a specific SSL port is specified
        host = new HostString(host.Host, SSLPort.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        // clear the port
        host = new HostString(host.Host);
    }

    var req = context.HttpContext.Request;
    var newUrl = new StringBuilder().Append("https://").Append(host).Append(req.PathBase).Append(req.Path).Append(req.QueryString);
    var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
    response.StatusCode = StatusCode;
    response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = newUrl.ToString();
    context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
    context.Logger?.RedirectedToHttps();
}
```

So this basically gets the current host name, and builds a new URL that looks the same except it has a `https://` in front. And then it sets a 301 HTTP status code and returns the new URL through the `Location` header.

The rule is then executed as part of the [`RewriteMiddleware`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.rewrite.rewritemiddleware?view=aspnetcore-2.1) which will basically just loop through all registered rules and will eventually run the above code and then end the response.

In contrast, this is how the [`HttpsRedirectionMiddleware`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.httpspolicy.httpsredirectionmiddleware?view=aspnetcore-2.1) [works internally](https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/blob/2.1.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy/HttpsRedirectionMiddleware.cs):

```
if (context.Request.IsHttps || !TryGetHttpsPort(out var port))
{
    return _next(context);
}

var host = context.Request.Host;
if (port != 443)
{
    host = new HostString(host.Host, port);
}
else
{
    host = new HostString(host.Host);
}

var request = context.Request;
var redirectUrl = UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(
    "https",
    host,
    request.PathBase,
    request.Path,
    request.QueryString);

context.Response.StatusCode = _statusCode;
context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = redirectUrl;

_logger.RedirectingToHttps(redirectUrl);

return Task.CompletedTask;
```

So this will get the host name from the incoming request, and then build an absolute URL using the `UriHelper` that looks exactly like the current request except that it uses the `https://` scheme. And then it sets a 307 HTTP status code result and returns the new URL through the `Location` header. Since it does not call later middlewares, this will also end the response.

So yeah, those two solutions are *very different* (**not**): They use pretty much equivalent code and produce the same result. The only actual difference is that the `HttpsRedirectionMiddleware` uses a [HTTP 307 status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307) by default.

If you prefer one status code over the other, you can totally configure *both* middlewares to use your preferred status code instead.

---

So which middleware should you use to enable HTTPS redirection? It doesn’t really matter. The ASP.NET Core templates come with the `HttpsRedirectionMiddleware` by default, but that middleware also only exists since ASP.NET Core 2.1.

I’d personally stick with the `HttpsRedirectionMiddleware` since it conveys its purpose very clearly. But if you have a `RewriteMiddleware` in place anyway, I would just replace the `HttpsRedirectionMiddleware` by a `RedirectToHttpsRule` for the rewrite middleware, so you just have a single middleware that performs redirects. – But in the end, it really doesn’t matter.

Comment: Thanks @poke for the very detailed answer! Do you know if I were to use the `HttpsRedirectionMiddleware` in conjunction with the `RewriteMiddleware` set only to do the www redirect, would it result in two 301 redirects (one for the https and one for the www)? As opposed to doing both the https and www redirects inside of the `RewriteMiddleware`, would that combine everything into a single 301 redirect?

Comment: No, both middlewares will terminate the request at the end without calling the next middleware in the pipeline. So whatever middleware is registered first will be executed and then end the response. So there won’t be any combination of effects.

Comment: Perfect, that's the clarification I was looking for. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I don't know how you came up with this much detail but it appears `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` uses a temporary redirect (Status307TemporaryRedirect), while `AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent()` implements a permanent redirect. (I can't imagine why anyone would want a temporary redirect to HTTPS.)